# Can I unlock any badges on the Stack Exchange network by playing Unikong?

Tags: achievements, unikong

Are there any badges on the Stack Exchange network that are unlocked by playing, or are otherwise related to, Unikong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, there are no badges you can unlock on any Stack Exchange site by playing Unikong.

This is similar to the last two April Fools games. StackEgg had no badges, and neither did the one two years ago, Unicoins.

Comment: StackEgg _was_  last year, you might want to change that :-)